# Текст при загрузке изображения

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, загрузка-изображения

Сейчас при загрузке картинки на сайт отображается следующее окно:

> [image: загрузка]

Можно заметить, что в текущем виде текст выглядит не лучшим образом. В частности:

- наличие запятой в начале строки;
- жирный текст в две строки.

Оригинальный текст такой:

> [**Drag and drop or click here** to upload your image (max 2 MiB)](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/53698126?key=afd2317ed89d04e1754f62929dc92d76)

И окошко выглядит так:

> [image: upload]

Текущий перевод:

> **Перетащите изображение или нажмите здесь**, чтобы загрузить его (не более 2 мегабайт)

Предлагаю его поправить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть интересный момент, который почему-то никто не заметил.
Если будет 2 жирных куска, то строки будут расположены адекватно.

[image: разметка]

[image: получится так]

Полагаю, этому будет соответствовать следующий вариант разметки:

```
**Перетащите сюда изображение** **или кликните для выбора файла**  
(не более 2 мегабайт)
```

> **Перетащите сюда изображение** **или кликните для выбора файла**
>   (не более 2 мегабайт)

---

После [фикса кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4927/176217) окно выглядит следующим образом:

> [image: итог]

Comment: Мне такой вариант нравится ещё больше: "перетащите сюда изображение" -- это просто в точку. @alexolut а вам как?

Comment: @AK, в комментариях нельзя звать тех, кто не участвовал в комментировании или правке ответа. Позови в соседнем ответе или в чате. А ещё обращаю внимание, что лимит на размер находится вне рамки.

Comment: Я видел, но всё равно выглядит красиво. Фраза "Вы также можете" -- она ведь тоже всегда за рамкой. Пока - имху лучший вариант.

Comment: @Qwertiy лимит вне блока это не очень хорошо, так как относится к загружаемой картинке. Хотя в целом выглядит неплохо. В идеале хотелось бы сохранить оригинальное форматирование.

Comment: @alexolut, запостил ещё один хак :)

Comment: @alexolut А по мне наоборот красиво именно тем, что условие за рамку попало и слилось с "вы можете использовать изображение из сети", они там как бы группируются в логический блок.

Comment: @AK если ограничение действует и на загружаемую из сети картинку, то, вероятно, в этом есть смысл. Хотя мне больше нравится вариант с <sub'ом>

Comment: @alexolut, на картинку из сети ограничений нет - она же никуда не загружается.

Comment: @Qwertiy Она загружается на тот же imgur.

Comment: @alexolut, o_O Я всегда просто ссылку подставлял руками :)

Comment: Ну, это можно и без обсуждаемого окна делать потому что.

Comment: @alexolut, но руками-то оно точно никуда не загружается ;)

Comment: Почему же? На комп того, кто видит тело вопроса. :)

Comment: Видимо [не хватает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhhdJ.jpg) дополнительного перевода строки?

Comment: @alexolut, ага. Ты два пробела не пропустил в конце строки? Ну или `<br>` тегом попробуй.

Comment: @Qwertiy я после жирных строк один пробел только оставил. Сейчас переделал на 2. Ждем обновления для проверки.

Comment: Не получается такого форматирования добиться. Два пробела не работают, а `<br>` вставляется как есть. :( Вероятно и `<sub>` не будет работать.

Comment: @alexolut, а если абзац? Т. е. пустая строка? UPDATE: Лучше не надо, там жесть :)

Comment: @Qwertiy я думаю, там любой тег будет экранироваться, т.е. только если markdown использовать, но как видно с двумя пробелами тоже не срослось. Можно попробовать явный перевод строки сделать. Так я ещё не проверял.

Comment: @alexolut, не сработает

Comment: Почему это вдруг? Может он как раз превратится в нормальный `<br>`.

Comment: @alexolut, потому что браузер превратит в пробел? Или что такое явный перевод строки?

Comment: Немного сломали опять.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё немного магии. Чтобы сделать текст чуть мельче и уместить в одну строку побольше, можно использовать верхний или нижний индекс. Однако, это не отменяет того, что надписи надо переформулировать. Жирная мне всегда не нравилась, а уж запятая в начале строки - это вообще жуть.

[image: Скриншот разметки]

[image: Скриншот результата]

Comment: Какой вид при этом должен быть у строки transifex, чтобы sup работал по Вашему мнению? В явном виде тег написать?

Comment: @alexolut, ага, написать тег. Вроде других способов нет? Только sub, а не sup, чтобы расстояние не увеличивать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможный новый вариант:

> **Перетащите или нажмите здесь** для загрузки изображения (не более 2 мегабайт)

Answer (score -1):

Ещё один вариант (по факту, вариация на ответ @alexolut):

> **Перетащите изображение или нажмите здесь** для загрузки изображения (не более 2 мегабайт)

Поясняю.

Вариант "для загрузки" вместо ", чтобы загрузить" - это шикарный ход, однозначно "за".

Однако я бы оставил слово "изображение" после "перетащите", как по мне это сильнее разносит через "или" два разных действия: или "драг-н-дропните сюда" или "нажмите здесь".

Я бы реально поставил именно "перетащите сюда" вместо "перетащите изображение", но получится масло масленное. Поэтому "перетащите изображение" -- неплохой компромисс.

Нужно посмотреть, как оно будет выглядеть, я так понимаю, что оно опять в две строки будет, да?

Update: Вот несколько вариантов:

[image: Вариант1]

[image: вариант2]

[image: Вариант3]

Comment: Ваш вариант по-прежнему будет отображаться с делением жирного текста на две строки.

Comment: @alexolut Вот честно: а насколько это критично? При чтении ваш вариант сильно уступает в понимании из-за выкидывания этого слова. Возможно, это лично моё восприятие, но я бы попробовал поискать ещё варианты. Насколько нужен вообще этот полужирный шрифт, может полностью от него отказаться? Или кардинально по-иному фразу перестроить?

Comment: Выделение нужно, т.к. оно учитывается при отображении текста на окне, если не будет выделения, видимо вообще всё поедет (это моя гипотеза). Хотелось бы сделать красиво, т.е. исключить вторую жирную строку.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, это как раз просто: берём и прямо в браузере меняем текстовку -- можно легко увидеть, как будет выглядеть. Прикрепил в пост несколько вариантов. Видно, что без жирного текст вылезает вверх -- т.е. отступы рассчитаны на пару строк и одна из них должна быть высокой.