# Несуществующее слово в интерфейсе

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, загрузка-изображения

Обнаружил в интерфейсе сайта употребление слова, несуществующего в русском языке (выделено на картинке ниже). Это всплывающее окно появляется при попытке прикрепить изображение к вопросу или ответу.

Английское слово "click" должно переводиться как "щёлкнуть". Иные варианты перевода [можно найти в терминологической базе Майкрософт](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/language/Search?&searchTerm=click&langID=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&Source=true&productid=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B).

[image: снимок экрана]

Comment: Связанный ответ: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4378

Comment: На планете вообще существуют такие люди, которых коробит слово "кликнуть" и они теряются и не знают что делать?

Comment: Вы встречали вообще где-то на нормальных адекватных ресурсах слово "щёлкнуть", которое означало "click"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я привёл ссылку в сообщении - Майкрософт использует именно такое слово в своей ОС и прочих продуктах. И если уж мы взялись переводить сайт, так давайте делать это до конца.

Comment: Клик - всеобщеупотребимый компьютерный термин, давно вошедший в обиход. Нет никакого смысла его менять на что-то совсем режущее ухо, неассоциируемое  и редкоупоминаемое. Всё равно что клавиатуру переименовать в "клавишная панель" или "коммутационная панель"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, "клик" - это не термин, а жаргон, использовать который в переводе интерфейса западло. А коммутационная панель отношения к клавиатуре не имеет. И вы это прекрасно знаете ;-) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коммутационная_панель

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вообще можно написать "нажмите".

Comment: @Suvitruf, так и было раньше, кстати

Comment: @Suvitruf "нажмите" хотя бы легче для восприятия. "Нажмите здесь" лучше, чем предлагаемое "Щёлкните". Однако предлагается именно это, поэтому я против ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . А щёлкать можно пальцами, по носу и кое-чем ещё... Но в таком контексте - фи.

Comment: Слово "кликнуть" в русском языке определенно существует, хоть и значит другое

Comment: [morfologija.ru :: кликнуть](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Лично я не согласен с сутью наезда на слово "кликните" (если уж сопротивляться всем новым словам, то нужно называть компьютеры как минимум вычислителями), но, пожалуй, здесь "нажмите" действительно будет смотреться лучше

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Заменить на "нажмите" действительно можно, к тому же это будет отражать ситуацию и с сенсорными экранами тоже. Использовать "щёлкните" здесь мне кажется не очень хорошим решением.

Применил данный вариант на transifex. Будет доступно после подгрузки базы и пересборки сайта.