# Окно загрузки картинки (снова) выглядит кривым

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, загрузка-изображения

Окошко загрузки картинки у меня выглядит сейчас так:

> [image: загрузка картинки]

Видно, что жирный текст вылезает за границы внутреннего прямоугольника, а ещё происходит наложение текста со ссылкой и размером.

Раньше было нечто подобное:

1. [Не получается нормально разместить текст в диалоге загрузки картинки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4925/176217)
2. [Текст при загрузке изображения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4372/176217)