# Как выложить скрин на сайт для демонстрации чего-либо?

Tags: поддержка, загрузка-изображения

Подскажите, как можно выложить скрин на этот сайт для демонстрации?

Comment: о чем речь? просто изображение? видео?

Comment: Да, только изображение

Comment: Либо можете весь экран сфоткать: клавиша Windows + Print Screen (вверху слева), и потом вы найдете скриншот в проводнике->Изображения->Screenshots.

Comment: ну как бы вопрос скриншотом в стаковерфлоу не имеет смысла а вот приложить ссылку и попытку хоть и не удачную не возбраняется

Comment: В форме для вопроса есть кнопка "Изображение". Нажимаешь и прицепляешь.

Answer (score 5):

Для добавления изображения в пост есть специальная кнопка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на нее открывается диалоговое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В которое можно перетаскивать изображения, вставлять с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

А также можно открыть окно выбора локального файла, либо вставить ссылку на картинку из сети.

Comment: И [дефективное окно загрузки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8128/176217).

Answer (score -5):

Инструмент ножници использую я

Comment: а где мне этот инструмент найти?

Comment: В поиск програм пиши "ножници"

Comment: @Артур Пишете в поиске винды "Ножницы", он найдет.

Comment: @VerNick Повторять за мной зачем?

Comment: @МиколаМірчук Я за вами не повторял, мы одновременно написали.

Comment: @VerNick Бывает)

Comment: Нет, ножницы на компе я найти могу, я имел ввиду как мне на этот сайт выложить скрин, чтоб кому либо, что-то про демонстрировать?

Comment: @Артур Значок изображения в панели вопроса.

Comment: @МиколаМірчук, поиск не дал результатов https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fhCb.png

Comment: @mymedia Думаю вы знаете в чем причина просто решили пошутить. В любом случае должен отметить что я имел в виду операционную систему Windows